# The color of my c++ code don t change when i type on Visual studio code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, colors

I am learning c++ in the university. Right now I am not sure why when I code, the color of my code stays black, red and blue. And also, Visual Studio wants me to change my shell.

[image]

Comment: The color is to help you. They mark different things in your code, such as types, literals, keywords and more

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to save the file as a .cpp file first for the colours to appear in your code.
2. You can try changing the colour scheme for VS Code by clicking on `View` > `Command Palette`. There, look for "Preferences: Colour Scheme" and change to a different colour theme.
   [image: Find colour scheme in options]

I'm using the VS 2019 Dark Theme and it should give you code that is colour coded like the image below.

[image: Colour coded code]

*Updated answer to add theming option.

Comment: Hey, I just changed it but, still the same color....